# How to properly alloc memory for *to in mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: mysql, c, linux

here is my code:

```
str col2;
mysql_real_escape_string(con, col2, col, strlen(col));
quote_vs[i2] = malloc(strlen(col2) + 2 + 1);
sprintf(quote_vs[i2], "'%s'", col2);
```

I don't know col2's length, how to alloc memory

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution: the mysql document say:

```
You must allocate the to buffer to be at least length*2+1 bytes long.
```